# How do I cluster rows of the DataFrame which contain a list of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

This is my DataFrame which contains a list of words. I want to cluster rows of the DataFrame together using KMeans or another clustering method. How do I do that?

```
0    [nature, car]
1    [view, technology]
2    [feel, great, trees]
3    [excited, concert]
4    [computer, mobile]
```

Comment: Are you asking to cluster at document level?

Comment: Yes. Clustering at document level and not just the words.